# How do I use a custom icon at a PinItButton of their SDK?

Tags: java, android, button, sdk, components

I want to use a custom icon for my pinIt button. I keep getting the old layout overwritten when I run my app while in the preview the icon that I prefer is shown.

```
<com.pinterest.pinit.PinItButton
        android:id="@+id/car_info_comment_pintrest"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/car_info_button_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_comment_pintrest"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_comment_pintrest"
        android:text="100"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it with a hacky solution. I've added another button and called the OnClickEvent of the PinIt button and made that buttons visibility: gone.

```
    holder.mPinterestButton = ((PinItButton) holder.content.findViewById(R.id.pin_it));
    holder.mPinterestButton.setImageUrl("http://placekitten.com/400/300");
    holder.mPinterestButton.setUrl("http://placekitten.com"); // optional
    holder.mPinterestButton.setDescription("A place kitten!"); // optional
    holder.pinterestButton = ((Button) holder.content.findViewById(R.id.car_info_comment_pinterest));
    holder.pinterestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.mPinterestButton.performClick();
        }
    });
```

XML:

```
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/car_info_comment_pinterest"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/car_info_button_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_comment_pinterest"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="100"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <com.pinterest.pinit.PinItButton
            android:id="@+id/pin_it"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
```